# jquery sortable('toArray') only if element belongs in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page with many div boxes rendered using bootstrap 3. I want some of them to be sortable. Each div that i want to be sortable has a specific data- attribute (ex: data-sortable="box-1", data-sortable="box-2" etc)

Doing this though:

```
$(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    placeholder: "sort-highlight",
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    handle: ".box-header, .nav-tabs",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    zIndex: 999999,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
     var columns = [];
        $(".ui-sortable").each(function(){
            columns.push($(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));
        });
    }
});
```

will add some other divs inside the array, because some static divs have their own mini-sortable items that i deal with elsewhere.
I want to somehow separate those, and insert only the divs with the specific data-sortable tag.

With this:

```
$(".row").each(function(){
   var divsWithTag = $(this).find('[data-sortable]');
}
```

i can get all the divs that i want. Is there a way i can tweak this line here

```
columns.push($(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));
```

to push only the divs that match elements inside divsWithTag variable?

Comment: you mean like `columns.push($(this).filter('[data-sortable]').sortable('toArray').join(','));`, if not: can you add a https://jsfiddle.net/ so everyone can test it ?

Comment: Maybe filter the line

`$(".ui-sortable").each(function(){`

using that custom attribute.

A jsfiddle would help.

Comment: yeah something like that! Although this one returns $(...).filter(...).sortable(...).join is not a function.
A fiddle is gonna be hard...I'll have to 'butcher' tons of code to create an example. Thats why i was asking if its even possible. So 'filter' could do that uh ?

Comment: I'll try make an example in fiddle. For starters i just wanted to know if its even possible to filter sortable like that.At least i not hopeless :)

Comment: Using `filter` and the fact that `toArray` returns an array of id-s, you could check: `$(this).sortable('toArray').filter(function(id) { return divsWithTag.is(id); }).join(',')` If you add the HTML structure to the question I could try to be more specific

Comment: Slight correction: `function(id) { return divsWithTag.is("#"+id); }` still need the `#` symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter`, and considering the fact that `toArray` returns an array of id-s. Below, the `.attr()` value is coerced to a boolean:

```
finalColumns.push($(this).sortable('toArray').filter(function(id) {
    return $('#'+id).attr('data-sortable');
}).join(','));
```

Or use `.is` (as in the original comment) instead of the id match /originally thought the attribute-match collection would only be looked up once/

http://jsfiddle.net/h8h9u0k7/3/

Comment: awesome!...this worked perfectly.Thanks!
So no need to grab all the data-sortable ids first and then compare them..It does it in one call.